# Did anybody ever migrate from Accurev to ClearCase?

Tags: version-control, migration, clearcase, accurev

I heard a lot of stories about people migrating from ClearCase to AccuRev. But I've never heard of migration in the opposite direction. Is it because nobody ever dropped AccuRev in favor of ClearCase?

Did you considered both and gone with ClearCase?

I know that AccuRev is a great version control system, but I want to know whether ClearCase is superior to AccuRev in some feature. If you actually choose ClearCase over AccuRev please write here the reasons behind you decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason you would migrate from Accurev to ClearCase would be if:

- ClearCase was part of a IBM deal including much more than a simple VCS (usually many servers and other softwares)
- IBM support was part of the consideration (IBM offering a very complete and detailed support for all its software)

But beside that external context, I don't know of any migration based on the value of ClearCase alone:
ClearCase is only maintained at this point, with fixes and patches, but without any major evolutions (beside the CCRC client) since 2004. Accurev is still very active.
A "ClearCase 2" already exists and is called [Rational Jazz SCM](https://jazz.net/projects/rational-team-concert/features/scm), part of the commercial offer called [RTC (Rational Team Concert)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/products/rtc/)

If anything, a migration from any tool to RTC would make much more sense.

---

Note that moving to RTC would be a very different move that just changing an SCM.
RTC provides a fully integration development lifecycle experience, with requirements up to builds and test plans, including SCM, instant messaging, full integration with Eclipse or Visual Studio (2005 or more), and so on.
That is what they call "Collaborative Lifecycle Management project, which coordinates the software development activities across requirements, development, build, and test".

The [Jazz platform](https://jazz.net/about/) in itself doesn't include an SCM, but rather is an "open platform for lifecycle tool integration", i.e. an [open-sourced Application **Hub**](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/jazz/), in order to make *any* tool (Rational or not) able to communicate one with another.

Choosing the "Source Control component of Rational Team Concert" is usually done in the context of a much larger migration, aiming to regroup in one referential (the [Jazz Team RTC Server](https://jazz.net/library/article/557/)) all development-related elements (sources, but also requirements, builds, tests, ...)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please add details about Jazz and RTC? Could there be any reason to prefer Jazz over AccuRev? I intend to use AccuRev ALM solution not SCM only.

Comment: @Yossi: details added. As I mention, Jazz in itself is just a Hub (so you wouldn't choose it to replace anything but to make existing tools work together). As for RTC, it is much more than just an SCM.